# PowerShell to export SMTPAddress details to .CSV failed?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I am writing this PowerShell script to export some information like:

```
Name 
Mail
ObjectClass
SMTP Address (only SMTP and smtp addresses)
DistinguishedName
RecipientTypeDetails --> This is to know what type of Mailbox (Shared, User,Resource,etc...)
WhenMailboxCreated
WhenChanged
WhenCreated
Identity
SKUAssigned
```

Because somehow it only shows the:
**Name, Mail, ObjectClass** and **DistinguishedName**, while the SMTP Address column is blank?

This is the script I've got:

```
function Get-EmailAddress
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
                   HelpMessage = 'What e-mail address would you like to find?')]
        [string[]]$EmailAddress
    )

    process
    {       
        foreach ($address in $EmailAddress)
        {
            Get-ADObject -Properties mail, proxyAddresses -Filter "mail -like '*$address*' -or proxyAddresses -like '*$address*'" | 
                Select Name, 
                       Mail, 
                       ObjectClass,
                       @{Label='SMTP Address';Expression={ $address.proxyAddresses | ?{ $address -Like "*smtp*" } -replace 'smtp:' -join ';' }},
                       DistinguishedName
            Get-Recipient $address | 
                Select DisplayName, 
                       RecipientType, 
                       RecipientTypeDetails, 
                       EmailAddresses, 
                       *When*, 
                       Identity, 
                       SKUAssigned
        }
    }
}

Get-EmailAddress HelpDesk,ServiceDesk | Export-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `?{ $address -Like "*smtp*" }` -> `?{ $_ -Like "*smtp*" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go through similar thing.

I'm not sure why, but you have to include "SMTP" Property in your `Get-ADObject -Properties SMTP` or just get them all by using `-Properties *`